# What does a taskset -p pid result of "e" mean?

Tags: taskset

I found the pid of my process. I ran taskset on the pid:

```
$ taskset -p 2059
pid 2059's current affinity mask: e
```

What does this affinity mask value "e" mean? I do not see anything about the possible output values in the [taskset docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset). The man pages are the same as the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `taskset` is a bitmask unless you specify otherwise.

```
taskset --cpu-list -p 2059
pid 2059's current affinity list: 1-3
```

Use `--cpu-list` to get more human comprehensible output:

> ```
>    -c, --cpu-list
>           Specify a numerical list of processors  instead  of  a  bitmask.
>           The numbers are separated by commas and may include ranges.  For
>           example: 0,5,7,9-11.
> ```

Comment: Someone should submit a bug report that this is not the Unix Way.  The bitmask should be printed in octal by default.  Without the leading `0` just in case that gives the game away. (-: